# Is there any value in creating a pool of Dom4J SaxReader objects?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I'm using Dom4J 1.4.2.

Right now my code creates a new SaxReader every time I want to parse a new XML document:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(  );
```

**Is there any value in creating a pool of SaxReader objects and just reusing them? How much overhead is involved in creating a new SaxReader on every call?**

My code could get one from the pool, parse the document then return it to the pool for another thread to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with all so-called performance issues and urges to pool objects: are you experiencing an actual problem, or are you trying to prematurely optimize here? Rolling your own pooling in Java has been [out of fashion](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275.html?ca=dgr-jw22JavaUrbanLegends) since at least 2005.

I peeked at the source code of [SAXReader](http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.4/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html#SAXReader()), and this is the constructor:

```
  138       public SAXReader() {
  139       }
```

There are no instance initializers, and the real work is done in the `read` method.

Comment: While doing proper profiling before optimizing code is the right approach, your evaluation of the SAXReader creation costs is wrong and misleading. Creating a SAXReader might very well be a costly operations. The constructor is just empty, because the reader is initialized in the read()-method, if the  private XMLReader field is null. Creating this XMLReader instance might result in a classpath scan! Also see: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-perfap2.html/#reuse